# is $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ equipped with following operations($p$ is prime):

$\forall (a,b),(c,d) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2$ :

$(a,b) \oplus (c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$

$(a,b) \odot (c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$

under what condition $(\mathbb{F}_p^2,\oplus ,\odot )$ is a field??

Comment: Hint - does that law of composition remind you of something, if you were to replace $\mathbb F_p$ with $\mathbb R$?

Comment: btw - someone down-voted, probably because you didn't discuss what you thought (i.e., showed  your work) about this problem

Comment: In my first comment : "that law of composition" = $\odot$.

Comment: @peterag it reminds me of complex numbers, the only thing that can go wrong is the inverse element under $\odot$

Comment: That's correct: ${\mathbb C}\simeq {\mathbb R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field. But  ${\mathbb C}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is not a  field. Why?

Comment: @peterag it's got something to do with The fundamental theorem of algebra?? i didn't study fields theory i just know the basic concepts...

Comment: No, that's not quite what I had in mind - but how does the poly $x^2+1$ behave over the complex numbers, compared to how it behaves over the reals?

Comment: for what kind of course is this, btw?

Comment: @peterag this question came up at first session of "introduction to linear algebra" after the definition of field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46129/discussion-between-peter-a-g-and-arsh-gh).